# How to run swapbyzero matlab function in a loop

Tags: swaps, matlab, interest-rate-swap

I made a for loop in Matlab in which I price a swap by using the swapbyzero function. The swapbyzero function requires a rates structure created by using the intenvset function from matlab. The problem with the loop is that it looks like the swapbyzero function is remebering some variables from the previous loop and therefore breaks. 
To be more specific. The first loop calculates a swap starting for example on the 3th june 2016 and the second swap starts at the 6th of september. What I see from the swapbyzero function is that it looks for the date of 3 june in the rates structure for the second swap what doesn't exist off course. 
Does anybody know if the swapbyzero function is remebering some variables from previous loops?

Thanks.

Comment: Some code would really help here. I haven't looked at the `swapbyzero` function but I find your explanation unlikely,  I'd say that would be a major bug in `swapbyzero`.

Comment: I would try to clear the variable of interest at the start of the loop (type: clear var_name), and recompute it, instead of "rewriting" new values on the existing variable.

Comment: probably it has something to do with the dates I put in. Difficult to share to total code here

Comment: I'm afraid that in the current format it's impossible to help you. Please distil your code in something that you can share and still fails. I'm closing for now but welcome a clarifying edit.

Comment: I agree. Was a bug in my code and solved it. Thanks